# getImageWritersByFormatName doesn't give proper values

Tags: java, native, ocr, tesseract, jai

```
Iterator<ImageWriter> writers = ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName(TIFF_FORMAT); 
if (!writers.hasNext()) {
    throw new RuntimeException(JAI_IMAGE_WRITER_MESSAGE);
}
```

`net.sourceforge.tess4j.TesseractException: java.lang.RuntimeException`

Need to install JAI Image I/O package. Exception is thrown because of `hasNext()`.

The same web application works in my mac machine, but not on an ubuntu machine. I am using tomcat server. Any help?

Comment: Is `TIFF_FORMAT == "TIFF"`? Just checking... :-) Most likely, this is a JAI installation issue. Either it's not there at all, or your Tomcat and/or web app is not picking it up. Do you install to the JRE's ext/lib folder or to Tomcat's shared/lib or common/lib folders?

Comment: yes, TIFF_FORMAT = "tiff" and JAI_IMAGE_WRITER_MESSAGE = "Need to install JAI Image I/O package.https://java.net/projects/jai-imageio/". I have the libs in the tomcat_home/lib folder

Comment: That seems to be the right place, given a fairly recent Tomcat. You could try to add an `ImageIO.scanForPlugins()` call (typically from a `ContextListener` or similar), if `ImageIO` somehow was initialized before Tomcat added it's shared classloader, to make the JARs in the lib folder available. If that doesn't help, I'd check the JAR files contents, to verify that they are correct.

Comment: Thanks! I figured out the mistake myself.. i had to set the classpath in tomcat/bin/setenv.sh

Comment: Good. You should post that as an answer. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks! I figured out the mistake myself.. i had to set the classpath to the jai_imageio.jar file in tomcat/bin/setenv.sh